# Pandas MultiIndex Data Frame Sorting

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a way to sort a multiindex data frame based on one of the indices.  Here's an example ...

I have ...

```
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('baz', 'y'), ('foo', 'y'), ('bar', 'y'), ('baz', 'z'), ('foo', 'z'), ('bar', 'z')],names=['first','second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6),index=mi)
print df
```

which produces

```
first second          
baz   y       1.902902
foo   y      -0.128341
bar   y       0.481100
baz   z      -2.185144
foo   z       1.015320
bar   z      -1.624616
```

If I do ...

```
df2 = df.sort()
```

I get :

```
print df2

first second          
bar   y       0.481100
      z      -1.624616
baz   y       1.902902
      z      -2.185144
foo   y      -0.128341
      z       1.015320
```

How can I sort df such that I get :

```
first second          
baz   y       1.902902
      z      -2.185144
foo   y      -0.128341
      z       1.015320
bar   y       0.481100
      z      -1.624616
```

Comment: How is that "sorting on one of the indices"?  How do you decide that "baz" comes before "bar"?

Comment: Because baz came before bar in the original data.  I don't want to change the order of first.

Comment: DataFrames don't keep any notion of "original order".  If the order in the original data is meaningful to you, create another column (or index level) that contains that information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how bar is sorted after foo, but I think this is what you want:

```
df.sortlevel(0)

                     0
first second          
bar   y      -0.114659
      z       0.453896
baz   y      -0.327006
      z       0.685782
foo   y       0.444256
      z      -0.167179
```